# Inserting array of data into database using Node.js

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, node.js, mongodb

As a rookie in web development I was hoping you can point me in the right direction on how to insert JSON data into a mongo database, to be used for automatic graph creation.

[I have a JSON response from this URL converted to a JavaScipt object looking like this:](https://api.twitch.tv/kraken/games/top)

```
[ { game:
     { name: 'Counter-Strike: Global Offensive',
       popularity: 244757,
       _id: 32399,
       giantbomb_id: 36113,
       box: [Object],
       logo: [Object],
       _links: {} },
    viewers: 246950,
    channels: 488 },
{ game:
         { name: 'League of Legends',
...
```

However I wonder how I can structure this data in a database so I can later graph my data according to the time and date it was fetched.

I figure that I would want to keep a list of Ids related to popularity and date.

Can you point me in a direction on how to read a JSON array and update a Mongo collection with the data so it looks something like this?

```
{
  _id: "32399",
  name: "Counter-Strike: Global Offensive",
  datapoints: [
                {
                  2016-05-18T16:00:00Z
                  viewers: 246950
                  channels: 488
                 },
                 {
                 2016-04-18T16:00:00Z
                 viewers: 230000
                 channels: 433
                 }
              ]
 }
```

I guess can iterate over every value using forEach. But is this the right method? and how do I sort the information? do I iteratively go through every entity and find viewer and channel values and save to a new document cache or use updateOne to update my database?

```
games.top.forEach(function(value) {
    console.log(value)
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, to start with you'd need to create a new Schema to determine the desired structure. Something along the lines of the following, although i'd advise reviewing the mongoose documentation before hand. http://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Game = new Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    datapoints: [{
        created: {
            type: Date,
            default: Date.now
        },
        viewers: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        },
        channels: {
            type: Number,
            default: 0
        }
    }]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Game', Game);
```

Then you'd simply need to create and save a new 'Game' instance for each row in the data.

```
var Game = require('your game model');

for(var idx = 0; idx < data.length; idx++) {
    var object = data[idx];

    var temp = new Game({
        name: object.name,
        datapoints: {
            created: Date.now(),
            viewers: object.viewers,
            channels: object.channels
        }
    });

    temp.save(function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }

        console.log('successfully saved');
    });
}
```

Please note, I haven't tested any of the above, it's straight from memory, so I'd very much suggest reading through the Mongoose documentation and perhaps following some tutorials to help familiarise yourself with the syntax and how Node and Mongoose work.

I hope this helps.

Comment: Your code looks great but you need to do yourself a question. How you determine whether all the games have been saved in order to make a response for the client?

Comment: @JoseHermosillaRodrigo Sorry, I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Are you suggesting provide reference on how to get data from the collection and output it based on specific parameters i.e. order or by id?

Comment: Thanks your code worked like a charm. Just had to edit the object a little. `for(var idx = 0; idx < games.top.length; idx++) {
    var object = games.top[idx];

    var temp = new Game({
        name: object.game.name,
        datapoints: {
            created: Date.now(),
            viewers: object.game.viewers,
            channels: object.game.channels,
        }
 
    });`

Comment: @dwigt Happy to help!